# Equivalent to jQuery closest() in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, findcontrol

Im trying to figure out a way to build a somewhat clever version of the jQuery closest method in C#. Im using a generic method to find the desired control and then index the control chain

```
public static T FindControlRecursive<T>(Control control, string controlID, out List<Control> controlChain) where T : Control
{
    controlChain = new List<Control>();

    // Find the control.
    if (control != null)
    {
        Control foundControl = control.FindControl(controlID);

        if (foundControl != null)
        {
            // Add the control to the list
            controlChain.Add(foundControl);    

            // Return the Control
            return foundControl as T;
        }
        // Continue the search
        foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
        {
            foundControl = FindControlRecursive<T>(c, controlID);

            // Add the control to the list
            controlChain.Add(foundControl);

            if (foundControl != null)
            {
                // Return the Control
                return foundControl as T;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

To Call it

```
List<Control> controlChain;
var myControl = FindControls.FindControlRecursive<TextBox>(form, "theTextboxId"), out controlChain);
```

To find the closest element of id or type

```
// Reverse the list so we search from the "myControl" and "up"
controlChain.Reverse();
// To find by id
var closestById = controlChain.Where(x => x.ID.Equals("desiredControlId")).FirstOrDefault();

// To find by type
var closestByType = controlChain.Where(x => x.GetType().Equals(typeof(RadioButton))).FirstOrDefault();
```

Would this be a good approach or are there any other cool solutions out there creating this?
Whats your consideration?

Thanks!

Comment: So controlChain contains all the parents of the specified ID control?

Comment: Yes, maybe breadcrumbs would be a better name. This is just a suggestion in how to build such a method. Maybe it's not the best model?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, besides "I made this, thoughts?"

Comment: So… Maybe a better fit for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: Sii, I wanted a review of my code and was not aware of the site Joan referred to. However, I was also curious if there where any other solutions available that could perform the task, so the question is not totally of track for SO anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
public static IEnumerable<Control> GetControlHierarchy(Control parent, string controlID)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl.ID == controlID)
            yield return ctrl;
        else
        {
            var result = GetControlHierarchy(ctrl, controlID);
            if (result != null)
                yield return ctrl;
        }
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fixed the script so it now compiles, this actually was the solution to my problem this day. Thanks a million!

Comment: Hi I am new to ASP.NET I am trying to do the same can you explain how this code work? thanks